# Merge / synonymise [fat] + [fats]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I found [fat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fat) with 25 questions and [fats](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fats) with 139, can a mod merge both?

Perhaps keeping [fats](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fats) since it has more questions, with a nice description it can become a tag for asking about the use of different types of fat (vegetable / animal).

Edit: I just bumped into these tags today and almost asked the same question... Maybe a mod could chime in this year? :)

Comment: Hello @mods, I was just about to post this same question again... Is there a reason not to merge these tags?

Comment: Hi Luciano, thank you for posting - and for re-bumping it. It seems that the question got overlooked the first time round. It sounds very sensible - I'd wait for a few days to see if somebody chimes in, and if not, I'd merge.

Answer (score 1):

I find that this makes sense, thank you for noticing.

I have a weak preference for leaving [fat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fat) and merging [fats](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fats) into it, but let's see if somebody supports the opposite direction.

**Update** Merge completed, we only have [fat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fat) left now, with a synonym.